# How to convert numeric to Thai language word in Java?

Tags: java, numbers, cpu-word, thai

I used the following code but it does not work:

```java
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;
    
        public class NumToword {
           public static void main(String str[]){
                String outputString = new String();
               Locale[] thaiLocale = {
                            new Locale("th"),
                            new Locale("th", "TH"),
                            new Locale("th", "TH", "TH")
                        };
               for (Locale locale : thaiLocale) {
                   NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
                   outputString = outputString + locale.toString() + ": ";
                    outputString = outputString + nf.format(573.34) + "\n";
                    System.out.println("word : "+outputString);
               }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the 
    `System.out.println("word : "+outputString);` outside of the for loop and to make it identical to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html remove the "word : ".  IE:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NumToword {
   public static void main(String str[]){
        String outputString = new String();
       Locale[] thaiLocale = {
                    new Locale("th"),
                    new Locale("th", "TH"),
                    new Locale("th", "TH", "TH")
                };
       for (Locale locale : thaiLocale) {
           NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
           outputString = outputString + locale.toString() + ": ";
            outputString = outputString + nf.format(573.34) + "\n";
       }
       System.out.println(outputString);
   }
  }
```